# Error "The Remaining Text Does Not Appear To Be Part Of The Formula" Crystal Reports 11.5.8.826

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm receiving the error stated in the question title in Crystal Reports. I've been troubleshooting for a while and I'm drawing blanks. I have some simple `If..Then..Else` statements and `Select..Case` statements in separate formulas, but I'm receiving the same errors for all of them. I'm writing the formulas in VB.Net and I suspect the issue is stemming from how I'm declaring my variables.

An example of a formula is:

```
Dim xyz As Number = {VALUE1} 
Dim array1 = New Integer() {1111, 1112, 1214, 1215} 
Dim array2 = New Integer() {1211, 1212, 1213, 1414, 1415} 
Dim array3 = New Integer() {1311, 1312, 1514, 1515} 
Dim array4 = New Integer() {1911} 

If Array.IndexOf(array1, xyz) >= 0 Then
    {VALUE2} & "_001"
ElseIf Array.IndexOf(array2, xyz) >= 0 Then
    {VALUE2} & "_002"
ElseIf Array.IndexOf(array3, xyz) >= 0 Then
    {VALUE2} & "_003"
ElseIf Array.IndexOf(array4, xyz) >= 0 Then
    {VALUE2} & "_004"
Else
    {VALUE2}
End If
```

When I enter that formula into the selected field it highlights everything after the `=` sign on line 1 (`Dim xyz As Number =...`).

After searching I've tried the use of colons with equal signs (`:=`) and semi-colons to end if statement, but couldn't find much more online to guide me. I did find threads suggesting a .dll  may be missing, but I don't currently have write permissions to a lot of areas on the system I'm working with so any fix like that is out of question for me.

My question in short is why am I receiving this error? Is it my `If..Then..Else` syntax or how I'm declaring variables? Or am I just not supposed to use VB.Net in crystal reports like I am doing?

Comment: Is that code example being used in a Crystal Report Formula?  If so, then it won't work because CR doesn't support VB syntax.  You need to write the formula in Crystal Syntax.

Comment: Oh, I assumed it could use VB, theres a drop down option for "Basic Syntax" and it seemed to highlight alot the VB I input as if I were writing it in Notepad++ or Visual Studio!.. guess I better go read up on crystal syntax!

Comment: It is modeled after VB, but it uses specific extensions to handle reporting, and the documentation/support for Crystal Syntax is much more thorough in my experiences. There are also some situations where Basic Syntax simply won't work, such as Record or Group Selection Formulas.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the information for the crystal syntax was more extensive, I ended up scraping half the work and started back at them in crystal, was a lot easier in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal does support a Basic Syntax, but it is more akin to VBA or VB6 than .Net, and also has its own peculiarities and limitations.

- No initalization on declaration
- Return value is "Formula =", it is not implied as in Crystal Syntax.
- Most functions and operators are more like the Crystal  Syntax than regular basic.
- All return values need to be of the same type.

Here is what I think  you were going for:

```html
Dim xyz As Number
Dim array1() as number
Dim array2() as number
Dim array3() as number
Dim array4() as number

xyz = {VALUE1}
array1 =  array(1111, 1112, 1214, 1215)
array2 = array(1211, 1212, 1213, 1414, 1415)
array3 = array(1311, 1312, 1514, 1515)
array4 = array(1911)

If  (xyz in array1) Then
    Formula = {VALUE2} & "_001"
ElseIf (xyz in array2) Then
    Formula = {VALUE2} & "_002"
ElseIf (xyz in array3) Then
    Formula = {VALUE2} & "_003"
ElseIf (xyz in array4) Then
    Formula = {VALUE2} & "_004"
Else
    Formula = totext({VALUE2})
End If
```

Comment: I think this may be exactly the solution to my issues with the VB. I rewrote it in crystal syntax using variable declarations as per what ajay said above, but ill try input what you have above tomorrow morning!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong to use in Crystal report, it always start with datatype then variable name like

```
numbervar pos;
stringvar cpu;
numbervar pos := 0;
stringvar cpu := 'abc';
NumberVar k := {@Counting_Data}/{@Counting_Fail}
```

This link for you similar question have [crystal reports error : remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088716/crystal-reports-error-remaining-text-does-not-appear-to-be-part-of-the-formula)

If you more learn about variable, there are 3 types of variable in terms of scope

- Local
- Global
- Shared

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_creating_variables.htm

Comment: Thanks Ajay, I corrected the variable declarations in some other formulas I had in crystal syntax and they're now working fine.